# How to call multiple str.contains on same column to take out data in pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, contain

I created a working example like this:

```
appart = OrderedDict([ ('Description', ['A LOUER F2 GRENOBLE Quartier Île Verte Rue Eugène Delacroix, place Dr Girard, proche tramway B et ligne de bus, 50,60 m² 4 ème étage avec ascenseur.', 'Actuellement libre.Transport : Ligne de bus C6 desservant le centre ville toutes les 10 mintram A arrêt Mc2Le stationnement.', ' Idéalement située: -à deux pas du Tram (Arrêt Gustave RIvet)-à 10 minutes du Centre Ville -supermarché à 2']),
      ('Loyer', [350, 267, 150]),
      ('Type',  ['Appartement', 'Maison', 'Parking']),
      ('Surface', [25, 18, 15]) ] )
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(appart)
df1
```

And this is my output :

```
    Description                                         Loyer   Type            Surface

0   A LOUER F2 GRENOBLE Quartier Île Verte Rue Eug...   350     Appartement     25
1   Actuellement libre.Transport : Ligne de bus C6...   267     Maison          18
2   Idéalement située: -à deux pas du Tram (Arrêt...    150     Parking         15
```

So for this DataFrame, I want to take out the area from each description and add it in a new column called `Quartier`. For example if the 1st description contains `('victor hugo|centre ville|hyper-centre-ville')` then add `'Centre Ville'` in `Quartier` column, if 2nd description contains `(''ile verte|Île-verte|ile-verte|la tronche')` then add `'Île-Verte'` in the `Quartier` column and so on for each area.

Comment: put description as text, not image, or even create minimal working example so everyone could run it and make changes.

Comment: can't you use `df['Description'].apply(callback)` and put all code in `callback` function ?

Comment: I edited, thnx @furas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use `df['Description'].apply(callback)` to execute function on every row and return new value which will create new column.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

appart = {
    'Description': [
        'A LOUER F2 GRENOBLE Quartier Île Verte Rue Eugène Delacroix, place Dr Girard, proche tramway B et ligne de bus, 50,60 m² 4 ème étage avec ascenseur.',
        'Actuellement libre.Transport : Ligne de bus C6 desservant le centre ville toutes les 10 mintram A arrêt Mc2Le stationnement.',
        ' Idéalement située: -à deux pas du Tram (Arrêt Gustave RIvet)-à 10 minutes du Centre Ville -supermarché à 2'
    ],
    'Loyer': [350, 267, 150],
    'Type': ['Appartement', 'Maison', 'Parking'],
    'Surface': [25, 18, 15]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(appart)
print(df)

# ----

def callback(text):
    if re.search('Victor Hugo|victor hugo|Centre-ville|centre ville|hyper-centre-ville|gare|grenette|saint André', text, re.IGNORECASE):
        return 'Centre-ville'

    if re.search('ile verte|Île-verte|ile-verte|la tronche|trois tours|île verte', text, re.IGNORECASE):
        return 'Île-Verte'

    return ''

df['Quartier'] = df['Description'].apply(callback)
print(df)
```

---

**EDIT:** I think you could nested first `np.where()` in second `np.where()` as third argument.

```
 np.where( ..., ..., np.where())
```

but I know if it gives correct result.

```
df['Quartier_2'] = np.where(df['Description'].str.contains('Victor Hugo|victor hugo|\
Centre-ville|centre ville|hyper-centre-ville|gare|grenette|\
saint André', case=False, na=True), 'Centre-ville',
    np.where(df['Description'].str.contains('ile verte|Île-verte|ile-verte|la tronche|trois tours|île verte', case=False, na=True), 'Île-Verte', ''))

print(df)
```

---

I use `apply()` with one column but you can use it with many columns or with full dataframe and then you have to use `axis=1` to gets rows instead of columns. And inside function you can get values from different columns.

```
def callback(row):

    text = row['Description']

    if re.search('Victor Hugo|victor hugo|Centre-ville|centre ville|hyper-centre-ville|gare|grenette|saint André', text, re.IGNORECASE):
        return 'Centre-ville'

    if re.search('ile verte|Île-verte|ile-verte|la tronche|trois tours|île verte', text, re.IGNORECASE):
        return 'Île-Verte'

    return ''

df['Quartier'] = df.apply(callback, axis=1)
```

Comment: This works perfectly for me, I appreciate your help @furas.


    `df['Quartier_2'] = np.where(df['Description'].str.contains('Victor Hugo|victor hugo|\
Centre-ville|centre ville|hyper-centre-ville|gare|grenette|\
saint André', case=False, na=True), 'Centre-ville',
    np.where(df['Description'].str.contains('ile verte|Île-verte|ile-verte|la tronche|trois tours|île verte', case=False, na=True), 'Île-Verte', ''))

    print(df)`

Comment: for two `np.where` it is OK, but for more `np.where` it will be messy :)

Comment: I already tried it for three ``np.where`` and it works well ;)